# How to sort each column of a df in descending order regarless of the row order?

Tags: r

I am trying to sort my data in descending or ascending order regardless of the data in the rows. I made a dummy example below:

```
A <- c(9,9,5,4,6,3,2,NA)
B <- c(9,5,3,4,1,4,NA,NA)
C <- c(1,4,5,6,7,4,2,4)
base <- data.frame(A,B,C)
df <- base
df$A <- sort(df$A,na.last = T)
df$B <- sort(df$B,na.last = T)
df$C <- sort(df$C)
```

We get this

```
structure(list(A = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, NA), B = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 9, 10, NA, NA), C = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to get something similar to `df` but my data have hundreds of columns, is there an easier way to do it?

I tried `arrange_all()` but the result is not what i want.

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- base%>%
        arrange_all()
```

Obtaining this:

```
  structure(list(A = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, NA), B = c(NA, 
    2, 4, 4, 5, 10, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, NA), C = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 5, 
    8, 7, 4, 1, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort each column individually :

```
library(dplyr)
base %>% mutate(across(.fns = sort, na.last = TRUE))

#   A  B C
#1  2  1 1
#2  3  3 2
#3  4  4 4
#4  5  4 4
#5  6  5 4
#6  9  9 5
#7  9 NA 6
#8 NA NA 7
```

Or in base R :

```
base[] <- lapply(base, sort, na.last = TRUE)
```